# Is there any difference between using @hostListener and ElementRef in a directive?

Tags: angular2-directives

In my **Angular 2** app I have a directive (@Directive, not @Component) which needs to access the element to which it's applied to **listen to certain DOM events**.

I managed to do it in the following 2 ways.
I would like to know if one is more appropriate (more efficient / reliable) and if there's any substantial difference between the 2 approaches:

**ElementRef**

```
 constructor(private _element: ElementRef) {}
 ... 
 this._element.nativeElement.addEventListener('drop', (e: any) => {
     ...
  }
```

**@HostListener**

```
  @HostListener('change') onChange(): void {
      ...
  }
```